# JavaScript - Call function from another module inside HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have a module `i18n.js` which I import in my `home.html`, like this:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <script type="module" src="../js/lib/i18n.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside the `i18n.js` module, I do the following:

```js
export const t = () => {};

//
// Global scope
//

window.t = t;
```

I understand that accessing the global `window` object is the way to go in order to be able to call a method from other file inside an HTML page. But... why is this code not working?

```html
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <p><script>t("title")</script></p>
    <script type="module" src="../js/lib/i18n.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined

Comment: 1. You are loading the script after calling it, hence undefined. 2. Putting code on HTMl will make it readable to everyone. So bad option. Instead, assign a selector to `p` and set it in JS on load

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to execute `t` before it's available on the window, you get an error but running the function through the onload as @Rajesh suggested works properly.

```js
const t = () => {
const pTitle = document.getElementById('pTitle');

  if (pTitle){
    pTitle.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  }
};

//
// Global scope
//

window.t = t;

export {
  t
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body onload="t()">
    <p id="pTitle">&nbsp;</p>
  <script type="module" src="./src/js/i18n.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```